# Conditional Expectation of Poisson Process Interarrival Events

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I'm having some trouble with something my professor said would be on our exam. For a Poisson process $N_t$ with interarrival times $X_i$, how is it that you find $E(X_i | N_t = n)$ (assuming $n\ge i$)? Similarly having trouble with finding $Var(X_i | N_t = n)$, but if I had one I could probably figure out the other pretty easily.

I'm thinking the solution might have something to do with the joint pdf of the arrival times, but I also might be overthinking it a bit. Any help with how to at least start this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key result behind the answer is the following theorem:

If $N$ is a homogeneous Poisson process over $[0,\infty)$ with some finite rate $k$, then the $n$ "events" of the Poisson process $X_i$, in increasing order and based conditionally on the fact that $n$ events occured, are distributed as the **order statistics** from a sample of size $n$ from the uniform distribution $U(0,t)$ on $[0,t]$.

Less formally, it means that I can take $n$ samples from a uniform distribution defined between $0$ and $t$, place them in order on that time interval, and they would be probabilistically identical to the interarrival points of a Poisson process over that same interval as long as only precisely $n$ arrival events occurred.

Two proofs with different levels of detail are discussed in Resnick's [book](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780817635916) and in many other stochastic processes textbooks. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Am I on the right track if I have the joint density function of the arrival times? Not entirely sure where to go from there

Comment: The way I would do it, which may be equivalent to what you're saying, is to label the interarrival intervals of the Poisson process and then calculate the conditional probability that exactly one event occurs in each of them (except for the final one) given that $n$ arrivals occur. This conditional probability should agree with the theorem above.